# Font awesome icons in repetitive

Tags: html, css

What if we use font awesome/css :bfore:After pseudo selector's **content code more than one time**. Example

```
#div:before {
 font-family: 'FontAwesome';
content:"\f0c9 \f0c9 \f0c9 \f0c9"; /*SEE I USED "\f0c9" more than one time */
}
```

**Live Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/1ep1vnL4/

So is this a good practice if i use it on production? 
becuase i want to use a icon 3 times so i am lazy put 3 new divs and repeat everything again.

Answer (score 1):

Is it bad to use `&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;` rather than `<div>&mdash;</div><div>&mdash;</div><div>&mdash;</div>`?

Font Awesome is just a font... it's the same as using any character from any other font. Using 3 or 4 characters in a `:before` pseudo element is not much different than using 3 or 4 characters inside a `<p>` tag.

There would be *much more* overhead if you were to use a different element (div, span, p) for each character.

Comment: Great! What if browser (like chrome) minify the css and remove spaces between characters? It's this a case?

Comment: You would need to test if minification was occurring... my browsers don't automatically minify things here.

Comment: Tested and minification is not removing spaces.

I think i should start using it. Thank you!